# Get value JSON to create a nested in golang

Tags: json, go, nested

I'm trying to create dynamically nested json from value FIELD_QUESTION and FIELD_ANSWER in golang.

my result json

```
{
"jumlahdata": 2,
"result": [
    {
        "QUICK_DATA_H_ID": "1",
        "ORDER_TRX_H_ID": "1",
        "FIELD_QUESTION": "FULLNAME",
        "FIELD_ANSWER": "RUBEN",
        "DTM_CRT": "2019-08-28T16:25:15.757Z"
    },
    {
        "QUICK_DATA_H_ID": "2",
        "ORDER_TRX_H_ID": "1",
        "FIELD_QUESTION": "ALAMAT_KTP",
        "FIELD_ANSWER": "jalandisana",
        "DTM_CRT": "2019-08-28T16:25:15.757Z"
    }
],
"statusdb": 200,
"statusload": 200,
"statusquery": 200
```

}

expected result nested

```
{
"jumlahdata": 1,
"result": [
    {
        "QUICK_DATA_H_ID": "1",
        "ORDER_TRX_H_ID": "1",
        "QUESTION":[{
            "FULLNAME": "RUBEN",
            "ALAMAT_KTP": "jalandisana",
        }]
        "DTM_CRT": "2019-08-28T16:25:15.757Z"
    }
],
"statusdb": 200,
"statusload": 200,
"statusquery": 200
```

}

can anyone help with this? Please let me know if I haven't been clear enough!

Comment: Can you provide some kind of explanation of the issue? Just a pile of sample code is not really enough to understand your question.

Comment: There is no function in the standard library that transforms your slice into the data structure you want, and SO isn't a coding service. You'll have to write that yourself.

Comment: @Adrian I want to nested my value result JSON sir. i was edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this tool can help you [JSON-to-Go - https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/](https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/)

```
type AutoGenerated struct {
    Jumlahdata int `json:"jumlahdata"`
    Result     []struct {
        QUICKDATAHID string `json:"QUICK_DATA_H_ID"`
        ORDERTRXHID  string `json:"ORDER_TRX_H_ID"`
        QUESTION     []struct {
            FULLNAME  string `json:"FULLNAME"`
            ALAMATKTP string `json:"ALAMAT_KTP"`
        } `json:"QUESTION"`
        DTMCRT time.Time `json:"DTM_CRT"`
    } `json:"result"`
    Statusdb    int `json:"statusdb"`
    Statusload  int `json:"statusload"`
    Statusquery int `json:"statusquery"`
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For that, personally i love to use [gabs](https://github.com/Jeffail/gabs) module which allows to handle those kind of situation in a more human friendly way.

---

For installing the module use:

```
go get github.com/Jeffail/gabs/v2
```

---

So take your json string and pass it to `gabs.ParseJSON` as follows

```golang
// jsonParsed var contains a set of functions to play arround
jsonParsed, _ := gabs.ParseJSON([]byte(`{
    "outter":{
        "inner":{
            "value1":10,
            "value2":22
        },
        "alsoInner":{
            "value1":20,
            "array1":[
                30, 40
            ]
        }
    }
}`))

// you can check for keys existence
exists := jsonParsed.Exists("outter", "inner", "value1")
// exists == true

// you can pretty print your json
fmt.Println(jsonObj.StringIndent("", "  "))

// you can search for specific values in your inner object
value, ok = jsonParsed.Search("outter", "inner", "value1").Data().(float64)
// value == 10.0, ok == true

// and much more ...
```

Take a look at the [documentation](https://github.com/Jeffail/gabs)